# how to navigate to another page at else statement in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a List of String stored in a variable like this:

```
var question = [
  'whats your favorite name',
  'whats your favorite color',
  'whats your favorite shape',
];
```

And have function that increase a variable each time I call it

```
void _Press(){
  setState((){
    _PressedNo = _PressedNo + 1;
  });

  print(_PressedNo );
}
```

And in my scaffold iam checking `if` the `_PressedNo` is smaller that List so it rebuild the scaffold with the new question each time i press the button till the questions finished like this :

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
  body:_PressedNo < question.length ? Container( 
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('yes'),
      onPressed:() {
        _Press();
      },
    ), 
  ) : // here i want to go to another page
```

And after the else `:` i want to go to another Flutter page, but I can only add widgets here so any solution how to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to take a bit of a different approach. The `build` method should only provide things that appear on the screen and not directly trigger a specific action or state change, such as navigating to another page.

You can handle this in the `_Press()` method:

```dart
void _Press() {
  if(_PressedNo < questions.length) {
    setState(() {
      _PressedNo = _PressedNo + 1;
    });
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).push(...); // navigate to another page

    // optionally set the _PressedNo back to 0
    setState(() { 
      _PressedNo = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Your build method should not change, since on this page it should always show the same button.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
  body: Container( 
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('yes'),
      onPressed:() {
        _Press();
      },
    ), 
  ),
);
```

Some other pointers:

- use lowerCase for functions and variables: `_press()` and `_pressedNo`.
- You can directly pass in the function to `onPressed` like `onPressed: _press,` (note that there are no parentheses since the function is not called but just passed along)

Comment: Thanks a lot that was very helpful for me..